# How to setup extended desktop to untilize 12 monitors?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, ati, gnome-panel

We have a 12 monitor setup and we're trying to make the GNOME panel display across all the monitors. But we don't know where to start.

How can we use this 4x3 setup to use the full combined resolution as one GNOME panel?

Video cards:
2 x VisionTek Radeon 6870 2GB Video cards

Comment: are you saying you have 12 monitors?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean:

1. do you mean you want all your monitors to have the same display?
2. do you want to combine all monitors and make it seem like its one monitor?

For answer to 1. :

- open System Settings and click on "Displays" (for Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10)
- select "Mirror displays"
- apply the configuration

For answer to 2. :

- open System Settings and click on "Displays" (for Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10)
- Place the (virtual) monitors shown (in Displays) in correct order of display (matching with the placement of real monitors)
- make sure the the "Mirror displays" is not checked and that all (virtual)monitors are switched on
- you could place launchers on all displays or on selected one
- apply the configuration

vote up if this works for you.